# Laravel 5 eloquent whereIn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Hope anybody can help me, I  need to search for items that have category id = x in the database

Example table items
id,cats,name etc...
cats = '1,19' or maybe just '19' or maybe '1,9'

So for this example I need a to search for items that have cats with 9

I tried this but when I search for 9 it also shows 19

```
$items = Items::where(function($query)use($cat) {
    $query->where('cats', 'like', '%,'.$cat->id.'%');
    $query->orWhere('cats', 'like', '%'.$cat->id.',%');
    $query->orWhere('cats', 'like', '%'.$cat->id.'%');
    })->orderBy('updated_at', 'DSC')->get();
```

I also tried something

```
$items = Items::whereIn(explode(',', 'cats'), $cat->id)->get();
```

but it doesn't work

Appreciate any help to find the easiest and shorts way of doing this, regards

Comment: Storing delimited data and queryin them will cause lots of problem and it's against normalization. You should create a pivot table for this if you can. And also you wouldn't need '%$cat->id%' when you are querying for 9 because it will always have comma before or after so if you remove your first where clause it should be ok

Comment: Hi engvrd, I tried removing the first query but it still shows 19 in the result
note: if cats is just '19' the field wouldn't have a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to understand what you want to achieve but I'll try. First of all as @particus mentioned the best way is to create pivot table when you don't need to worry about such things.

But the solution if you have list of ids in a columns separated by coma is not storing values like

```
1,2,3
```

but always adding `,` at the beginning and at the end, so it should be in this case:

```
,1,2,3,
```

This way, if you have in your table `,19,2,3,` and you want to search for value `9`, you should use look for `,9,` string, for example:

```
$id = 9; 
$items = Items::where('column', LIKE '%,'.$id.',%')->get();
```

Now for above string no record will be found, but if you have `,9,2,3,` or just `,9,` the desired record will be found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL, you can use the FIND_IN_SET function.

```
$items = Items::whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(".$cat->id.", cats)")->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Please note, this will not use any indexes defined on the cats column. Storing array like data in a field is usually a big red flag. You would benefit by normalizing this out now, rather than trying to work around the current design.